# Can I Go Back to a Previous Git Clone

Tags: git, git-clone

I am using TortoiseGit (i.e. right-click on the Windows Explorer folder followed by selecting Git Clone....).

If I do two Git Clones to different folders, can I switch back to the first and use it (i.e. develop and check in from it)? Both clones are up to date (i.e. on the same commit). Is any information kept that is specific to the latest Git Clone that would prevent this?

My goal is to verify my check in without permanently switching to source of a new git clone. I have information associated with the original git clone (e.g. stashes). Perhaps, there is a better way to meet my goal.

I have looked at documentation such as [Git Basics][1]. Also, this does note have to do with commit level so I did not see answers on stackoverflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for an optional central configuration file, all git information is local to each repository - so what you do in one (cloned) repository has no effect on what you do in another (cloned) repository. The only way to transfer information is to push from one repository and pull from the other (or push/pull directly between the repositories).